# WebPack: compile SCSS files to their own files

Tags: webpack, sass

I'm trying to configure Webpack to compile som SCSS files to CSS for me, which works like it's intended, with one exception.

I'd like webpack, to keep the desired directory structure with my stylesheets, instead of bundling into a huge CSS file.

Every solution, with MiniCssExportPlugin and extract-text-webpack-plugin just does the bundling in one file, which is not desirable for me, since I don't want to create a Single page application.

Comment: Nop, no way to do that. Webpack is a bundler, different than other solutions like gulp. You won't be able to achieve it.

Comment: Pon, there is a way to do that... Webpack is only a nodejs software...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to specify an output entry for each your scss files...

```
entry['myStyle'] = 'myFile.scss';
```

In specifying the output to keep the original filename

```
output: {
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
```

The only problem is that it will generate too an `'.js'`

but:

You can delete the extra js files generated for your scss file in using the 'EventHooksPlugin' in firing a done event inside which you'll delete them

Comment: sorry for the late answer, but it's not really convenient to have to administrate every css file I add. Has anybody written/can one write a loader, which could be put at the beginning of a chain, creating separate files for every css file?

Comment: You've got the options in webpack, so you can just loop inside you scss directory, with nodejs fs .... in order to add them in the entry.